# List all usages of an environment at the top of every page on which it is included

Tags: header-footer, environments

I have a `question` environment defined as follows:

```
\newenvironment{question}[1]{
    \vspace{.10in}
    {\bf #1}
}
```

The argument is the "question name". I would now like to include the name of every question which appears on a page in the header of that page. For example, if a page includes questions `foo` and `bar`, I want `foo, bar` to appear in the header. In particular, if a question spans multiple pages, I want this question to be listed *on every page it was split across*.

This is somewhat similar to listing the chapter name in the corner, however I will often have multiple questions on one page.

My goal is closely related to [Decorate every page of an environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499167/decorate-every-page-of-an-environment), however rather than simply identifying that there exists a question on the page, I need to store a list of those questions.

How can I do this in LaTeX?

Comment: Unrelated: `\bf` has been outdated since 1993! Use `\textbf{#1}` instead.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26143/193767